# TCS DCA question : Mini grocery store in python

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
id_num=[101,102,103,104]
price = [40,50,60,70] 
stock = [10,14,14,13] 
new = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id_num':id_num,
     'price':price,
     'stock':stock
     })
try:
    inp_num=int(input("enter the id number:")) 
    qua = int(input("enter the quantity:")) 
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid")

if([new['id_num']==inp_num]):
    total = price*qua
    print(total)
```

> Explanation
>
> **Program : enter the id and stock value that customer wants to buy and calculate the price according the quantity** Example input : 1 >
> id = 101
> quantity = 5 output :
> total price = 200  2> id = 103     quantity = 20 output ;    out of stock"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the final solution

```
id_num=[101,102,103,104]
price = [40,50,60,70] 
stock = [10,14,14,13] 

try:
    inp_num=int(input("enter the id number:")) 
    qua = int(input("enter the quantity:")) 
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid")
  
if inp_num in id_num:
    ind = id_num.index(inp_num)
    if qua <= stock[ind]:
        total = price[ind]*qua
        stock[ind] -= qua
        print(total)
    else:
        print("out of stock")
else:
    print("no product available")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def new_funct(new):

    try:
        inp_num=int(input("enter the id number:")) 
        qua = int(input("enter the quantity:")) 
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid")
    
    list_of_value = new['id_num'].tolist()
    if inp_num in list_of_value:
        index_prod = list_of_value.index(inp_num)
        
        if qua <= new['stock'][index_prod]:
            total = new['price'][index_prod]*qua
            new.at['stock', index_prod]  = new['stock'][index_prod] - qua
            print("total price =",total)
        else:
            print("out of stock")
    else:
        print("no product available")
    return new
id_num=[101,102,103,104]
price = [40,50,60,70] 
stock = [10,14,14,13] 
new = pd.DataFrame({'id_num':id_num,'price':price,'stock':stock})

while True:
    new_funct(new)
```

Comment: Its shows me no product available even after give the input like id=101,quantity=5

Comment: @Exclusive, please test it now.